# Pure Redux VS ngrx with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, state, ngrx

What are the pro and cons of using either pure Redux or ngrx with Angular2/4?

I have been using both in differenet projects but am still wondering which one is the most efficient and fastest.

Answer (score 3):

It ends up that **ngrx** and **Redux** follows mostly the same ideas and help solving pretty much the same issues.

That said, angular uses Rxjs a lot, specially Observables, and as **ngrx** is also built upon Rxjs, the integration is a little bit easier and smoother

Regarding performance, if there is a component for which the entire state is in store, and the async pipe is used to output data to the view, you may use another change detection strategy for this component and this may lead to a performance improvement, specially on large applications. You may do it by setting changeDetection to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on @Component decorator. You may find more information on that [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html).

Also, on this [thread](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/16) you may find a detailed discussion on **ngrx/store** vs **Redux**.

Answer (score -1):

ngrx/store was created specifically for Angular2.
The detailed reasons can be found here:

https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/16